# PHP - MySQLi Prepared Update Statement Throwing Errors

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-update, prepared-statement

The code:

```
function getRealIpAddr()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}
/* ^^^ taken from http://roshanbh.com.np/2007/12/getting-real-ip-address-in-php.html */
$time=(string) time();
$ip=getRealIpAddr();
$username=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['Username']);
//$pwcde is defined as a hashed password from a form
$iptme=mysqli_prepare($connect, "UPDATE users SET ip_last=?, time_last=? WHERE username=? AND password=?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($iptme, "ssss", $ip, $time, $username, $pwcde);
mysqli_stmt_execute($iptme);
```

When this code runs, I get:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be
>   mysqli_stmt, boolean given in....
>
> Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt,
>   boolean given in....

Which obviously means `mysqli_prepare` failed (returned false).  I know the connection is good because other statements before it run fine.  But this is the only UPDATE statement with 2 fields to `SET`.  I cannot figure out a solution to the problem.

What is the syntax error or problem causing the function to fail?

Comment: Make sure you close previous statements before preparing this query, if you try to prepare query when one statement is still not closed in mysqli then it throws error

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  I called mysqli_stmt_close() on the previous statement and the code executed normally.

Answer (score 1):

It's good that you know that the query failed, if the `$iptme` gets the value false. But did you know you can test for this before you receive the fatal error or warning trying to use false as a statement resource? And did you know you can query the MySQL error message?

Any time you `prepare()` or `execute()` a query, use the API to get the error message:

```
if (!($iptme=mysqli_prepare($connect, ...))) {
  die($connect->error);
}

...

if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($iptme)) {
    die($iptme->error);
}
```

Errors can occur either during prepare or execute, so you have to test for return value in both cases.

Or alternatively, you can enable mysqli to throw exceptions when errors occur on prepare or execute, so you don't have to write the repetitive code to check return values. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php

PS: If you use bound parameters, *don't* use mysqli_real_escape_string(). You'll get literal `\` characters put into your SQL queries.